# How to spread single change through multiple reports?

Tags: xml, architecture, reporting-services, dictionary, metadata

I am solving a task. Business people just decided that they want to change name of one parameter in *.rdl reports. But this parameter is in hundreds of reports, and this will be pain in the ass to do manually.

I have some foggy vision to build some business dictionary DB, where every dimension, measure, etc would have Name and description. Once I change name of dimension in this dictionary, it should spread by some automatic job to all reports.

The name of parameter is usually set in "Prompt" in our reports.

How to technically solve spreading of change to reports? Do you have any ideas? The biggest issue for me is finding of right "Prompt" in *.rdl.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a sanp with powershell just iterate through all of the rdl files(treating as xml), and do you replace . you will need to republis hthe reports of course you could also do this directly from the tables in Report database but that would be unsupported... here is an example powershell script:

here is a basic script that may help get you started: 
[Using Python to scrape DataSet and Query data from RDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206993/using-python-to-scrape-dataset-and-query-data-from-rdl/3220888#3220888)

you will need to tweak it a bit; but it solves some of the hard parts